# Is 5400 RPM HDDs sufficient for a File/Backup Server?

Tags: hard-drive

I want to add a 1.5 - 2 TB hard drive to a Linux file and backup server we have in the office.

Will it make a difference if I'm using 5400 RPM vs a 7200 RPM hard drive? I was thinking about getting a Western Digital Green Drive or Samsung Ecogreen or similar.

Note: not always the case, but this server in particular is using a Fast Ethernet 100Mb/s network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.  If you are planning to use this drive as backup only, with occasional access, 5400 rpm shouldn't be a problem.

5400 rpm drives are still used in laptops and external enclosures all the time.  I would see if you can get a bigger cache, which will help the speed when you need it.

Comment: i have two WD Green drives in a enclosure running from my mac over ethernet, works great and i have no complaints for speeds, transfering to/from mac to windows 7.